# Understanding interval function and its parameters in python Hetland's book example

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, parameters, iteration

Got this example function from Hetland's python book.

```
def interval(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop=0, start
    result = []

    i = start
    while i < stop:
        result.append(i)
        i += step
    return result
```

What are both starts doing in the if statement? And why is it there twice? I changed the latter start to an int and that changed the length of my list to that int.

I also can't seem to wrap my head around the interation part. In the example, start = 10. So, when iterating... while 10 < 0 it will continue to grow the list, increasing the count by step=1 each time. But, 10 isn't less than 0. How'd run in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assignment should be parsed as

```
(start, stop) = (0, start)
```

That is, `interval(10)` is equivalent to `interval(0, 10)`. Even though the first parameter's *name* is `start`, it's really the `stop` value if only one argument is provided.

The `while` loop is equivalent to the more straight-forward `for` loop

```
for i in range(start, stop + 1, step):
    result.append(i)
```

except `interval` lets `start`, `stop`, and `step` all have types other than `int`.

---

A better design might be to require the use of keyword-only arguments, so that there's no ambiguity in the body of the function in how each parameter is used:

```
def interval(*, start=0, stop, step=1):
    result = []
    while start < stop:
        result.append(start)
        start += step
    return result
```

Now you can call `interval(stop=10)` or `interval(start=3, stop=10)`; either way, the parameter `start` is actually the starting value in both cases. It's a trade-off, though, in that you can no longer write `interval(10)` for what would be expected as the most common use case.

Comment: Oh, so it's akin to `while 0 < 10`

But, why is the parameters structured that way. I'm not sure if I came across it before in the book. I thought that it'll be in order unless the argument was explicitly stated.

Second example, `interval(1, 5)` makes sense and follows the order. Why is it that if there's only one parameter, it gets assigned to stop instead of start?

Comment: It's simulating how `range` works. `0` makes for a good implicit starting point; there is no good implicit stopping point.

Comment: You also can't override the function with different signatures; you can't define `def interval(stop)` and `def interval(start, stop)` separately, which is why you are stuck with a parameter whose semantics change depending on how may arguments are passed.

Comment: Ah yes, range has defaults. Start and step are optional. Thank you for the explanation.